# React not rendering class

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, reactjs

I believe I have a syntax area somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Note: I am new to React and I am using Sharepoint to develop.

My Js file:

```
var newt = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            greeting: 'This is really',
            thing: 'code stuff'
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="react-newt">
                {this.state.greeting} {this.state.thing}!
            </div>
        );
    }
});

$(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('newt')) {
        React.render(
            <newt />,
            document.getElementById('newt')
        );
        console.log('newt');
    }
});
```

And my HTML file:

```
<div id="newt"></div>
```

I inspect the console and I see this:
[image: Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a capitalised name for the component. JSX treats lowercase as a built-in HTML component. See [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for more details.

```
var Newt = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            greeting: 'This is really',
            thing: 'code stuff'
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="react-newt">
                {this.state.greeting} {this.state.thing}!
            </div>
        );
    }
});

$(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('newt')) {
        React.render(
            <Newt />,
            document.getElementById('newt')
        );
        console.log('newt');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That worked...getting used to React is taking me some time, I'm pretty slow when it comes to learning from the docs.